# Android material design - for whom?? Developer or Designer?

Tags: android-layout, android, material-design

I know this is a silly question. But I read the whole spec provided by Google from -
[Material Design Specification](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html)

After going through the whole document I understood that there are huge new things in material design which are more important to know for a **designer** than a **developer**.

I am a programmer not a designer. Now I'm going to tell my designer to read the whole document of material design before me. Once he is finished with it I'll start. :)
I'm not sure weather I'm right or wrong.

**But I'm very much interested to know your thinking about material design in this regards.**

Comment: Closing as unclear what you are asking and, even if you make it clear, I think it will still be off-topic. If you are going to develop for a framework, you should understand the guidelines for UX/UI design.

Comment: Both of you should read it. In my case, just me. ;)